# Recursive Function to Calculate Exponential without " * "

Tags: python-3.x

Write a function power that accepts two arguments, a and b and calculates a raised to the power b.
Example:
power(2,3) = 8
Raise a TypeError with the message Argument must be integer or float if the inputs are anything other that ints or floats.
Note: Don't use **

My code below is not given me my desired output. Please what could be wrong?

```
def power(a, b):
    if a == type(int) or a == type(float) and b == type(int) or b == type(float):
        def add(a, b):
            num = a
            for i in range(b):
                num += 1
            return num

        def multiply(a, b):
            num = 0
            for i in range(b):
                num = add(num, a)
            return num

        def power(a, b):
            num = 1
            for i in range(b):
                num = multiply(num, a)
            return num
    else:
        return "Argument must be integer or float"
```

Comment: So you can't use `*`or `**`?

Comment: And if the output is wrong, you need to debug it. You have 3 inner functions defined. Which is returning bad results?

Comment: its not passing the if condition for the functions to run

Comment: The check should be `if type(a) == type(int)` shouldn't it? A number won't be equal to a type.

Comment: still the same result

Comment: Please don't edit the code in the question to get rid of the problems you were reporting. That makes the answer below not make any sense. If you have further issues with your code, you can add another code block with an explanation of the new issues, or just ask a separate question about them (linking back to this question if context is necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of issues with your code.

To start with, your type checking is fractally wrong (it keeps getting more wrong the more deeply you look into it). You should probably use `isinstance(a, (int, float)) and isinstance(b, (int, float))` rather than the backwards stuff you have now. Currently you're checking if `a` and `b` are equal to the class `type` (which is the type of `int` and `float`). You also have the expression grouping wrong, as the `and` operator binds more tightly than the `or`s do (your code does `a or (b and c) or d` when you wanted `(a or b) and (c or d)`).

Next, you're defining new functions do do your power calculation, but you never call them from the outer `power` function (so they'll never do anything). If you want to keep the inner functions, you need a `return power(a, b)` call somewhere. You could however simplify things a bunch by getting rid of the inner functions and just doing the computation directly in some nested loops. Nested functions are only very rarely necessary.

You're also not doing what you're supposed to do in the error case. You're supposed to `raise` a `TypeError`, not return a string.

And finally, I think you've made the whole problem much more complicated than necessary. Your assignment says not to use `**`, but I suspect you're still allowed to use the `*` and `+` operators. I'd just do some multiplying in a loop rather than redefining everything from the ground up (which doesn't even work, since your `add` function needs `+=`).

One further note: The problem statement doesn't say if `b` (the exponent) is always going to be a whole number, or if it can have a fractional part. Handling fractional exponents is a lot more difficult than handling whole number exponents, so I'd ask your instructor if that's actually part of the assignment before spending a lot of time on trying to solve it. It may be that you need to support both `int` and `float` types, but even if `b` is a float it will still be a whole number.

Comment: Thanks!  Will use * for another version. But to correct the above code; am having issues with incorporating "return power(a, b)" in the function

Comment: You'd probably want that just above the `else`, at the same indentation level as the `def` statements for the inner functions. It's rather awkward that you're using the same name for the inner `power` function as the outer one, but it's not a problem that will prevent the code from running (it just looks like you're doing recursion when you're not).

Comment: it worked fine after the corrections, you are superb.